Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_ on Flutter iOS
I am setting a flutter project on Mac M3. I am getting the following error
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                      2,794ms
Xcode build done.                                           36.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_Builtin_float


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_errno


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_math


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_signal


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_stdio


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_time


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftsys_time


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftunistd


Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

OS : mac OS Sonama Version 14.7 (23H124)
Xcode : 15.4
Flutter : 3.22.2

Same issue. 5 days ago build was fine but today getting the error.

The issue is because of the FBAudienceNetwork. It is updated yesterday. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/1/5/FBAudienceNetwork/6.16.0/FBAudienceNetwork.podspec.json

I am updating with an another solution that worked for me in my particular use case. Deepak's solution needs to change the pubspec to a different branch. A.Ktns Solution of updating podfile.lock don't work great if ci cd and in automation.
target 'Runner' do
    use_frameworks!
    use_modular_headers!

    pod 'FBAudienceNetwork','= 6.15.0'

    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end


For me, the issue is because of the FBAudienceNetwork. I have facebook_app_events dependency in my Flutter app.
FBAudienceNetwork is updated recently with version 16.6.0.
I have override the facebook_app_events from https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/tree/fix/iOS-issue-0.19.4. It is using the FBAudienceNetwork version 16.5.0
  facebook_app_events:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events
      ref: fix/iOS-issue-0.19.4

Update:
  facebook_app_events:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events
      ref: 3e4e062ded3eb92b37e43c274ee84da4a21edfa2


Worked for me. Thats the sad part about 3rd party plugins. Thanks a lot!

Worked for me as well, thanks for the hint!

this one worked for me. Although there is another solution that doesn't require a change in pubspec. This one -> https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/issues/361#issuecomment-2343541025

Sorry this branch is merged to main with 16.6.0. We will review is the update more stable with 6.15.0

please use this ref instead of fix/iOS-issue-0.19.4
ref: 3e4e062ded3eb92b37e43c274ee84da4a21edfa2

I encountered this issue as well. I found that it was related to an upgrade of some Facebook libraries. Here's the error log:
CopyUndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_Builtin_float", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_Builtin_float_$_FBAudienceNetworkSwift in FBAudienceNetwork[x86_64][2](FBAudienceNetworkSwift.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_Builtin_float_$_FBAdFilterEngine in FBAudienceNetwork[x86_64][3](FBAdFilterEngine.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_Builtin_float_$_FBAdMAISKOverlayManager in FBAudienceNetwork[x86_64][4](FBAdMAISKOverlayManager.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swift_Builtin_float_$_FBAudienceNetwork in FBAudienceNetwork[x86_64][406](FBAudienceNetwork.o)

I've updated the Podfile.lock to use these versions of Facebook libraries:
- FBAEMKit (17.0.2):
    - FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (= 17.0.2)
- FBAudienceNetwork (6.15.1)
- FBSDKCoreKit (17.0.2):
    - FBAEMKit (= 17.0.2)
    - FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (= 17.0.2)
- FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (17.0.2)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you go to Podfile.lock, you will find an entry that looks like this:
- FBAudienceNetwork (6.16.0)

Not the one under facebook_app_events, but the one that is not under any other value.
If you change  - FBAudienceNetwork (6.16.0) to  - FBAudienceNetwork (6.15.0) and then do cd ios and pod install, you will be able to build your app.
Note that, this is a temporary solution. You should wait for an official update with an official fix for this.
Also, some people said that updating your XCode to the latest version (16.0) might also fix the issue.

Another solution, you can lock the FBAudienceNetwork version to 6.15.2 in your Podfile instead of Podfile.lock (generated file). Then just remove Pods folder and Podfile.lock file in ios folder and run your app again
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # This is just a temporary solution to fix the iOS build issue. We need to remove this line after the author releases a new version of [flutter_facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events)
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '6.15.2'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

